# What's the difference between "Select" and "Select-Object" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In Windows PowerShell, is there any difference between the `Select-Object` and `Select` cmdlets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accroding to the [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) about the `Select-Object` cmdlet, `Select` is just an alias for `Select-Object`:

> You can also refer to the `Select-Object` cmdlet by its built-in alias, `select`. For more information, see [about_Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Generally, use `Get-Comand <name>` to get information about a command, which will also reveal its type, such as `Alias` in this case and underlying command